# Проверка permissions на телефонах Xiaomi для API<23

Tags: java, android, mobile-development, android-permissions

Как известно у Xiaomi есть своя система разрешений и работает она до 6 андроида, где новая система запроса разрешений появилась повсеместно. Я тестирую приложение на xiaomi redmi 3 c андроидом 5.1.1 на борту. При попытке задействовать камеру устройства выплывает сообщение на запрос этого самого разрешения. Но как быть если я хочу проверить дано ли это разрешение до того как будет непосредственно использоваться камера? (например при запуске приложения).
Пробовал стандартный способ:

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "android.permission.CAMERA");
```

он вернул 0, хотя разрешение на камеру не было дано.

Также пробовал способ исключительно для xiaomi:

```
boolean b = hasSelfPermissionForXiaomi(getActivity(),"android.permission.CAMERA");

private boolean hasSelfPermissionForXiaomi(Context context,String permission){
String permissionTop = AppOpsManagerCompat.permissionToOp(permission);
if(permissionTop == null){
    // not dangerous
    return true;
}
int noteOp = AppOpsManagerCompat.noteOp(context,permissionTop, Process.myUid(),context.getPackageName());
return noteOp == AppOpsManagerCompat.MODE_ALLOWED && checkSelfPermission(context,permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;}
```

Но этот метод тоже дал неверный результат. Господа разработчики, а как вы боретесь с устройствами xiaomi?

Comment: Не пробовали смотреть популярные библиотеки и их реализацию? Возможно кто то уже решал эту проблему

Comment: @iamthevoid слышал только о PermissionsDispatcher, но там они используют стандартный механизм, как я описал в первом способе

Comment: В проекте, над которым я работаю, мы используем RxPermissions. Вообще github - search - android runtime permissions. Там около 5 проектов с большим количеством stars, можно их поресерчить